# Make GPT partition tables accept variable volume size

Tags: linux, partitioning, gpt, disk-image

I often copy SD-cards or other flash drives used as system disks for small computers (Raspberry Pi, NVidia Jetson, small x86 PCs)  to image files for backup.

However, when restoring those backups, the target volume almost every time does not exactly match the source volume size, eg. SD cards even from the same vendor differ in size slightly, or small SD cards are even phased out and not available on the market anymore. So I always choose from almost-equal up to larger cards.

It seems that GPT partition tables are bad at handling this changes, as the resulting copies do not boot the target device anymore. I then regulary use tools like GNU parted or gdisk to check those drives and rewrite the partition tables - there is often one complaint about the drive being larger then the GPT states (ok I guess, the latter sectors will just be unused then), but also the "backup GPT" is considered damaged - my guess is that these tables are placed depending on the drives total block count or something?

So how to make an image that will boot on first attempt, without "repairing" it after writing?  It seems to be possible, as vanilla images for small computers are often shipped very small and they always boot, even if written to much larger disks.

Comment: I strongly doubt those two issues could impact boot-ability, as long as the primary GPT is not outright corrupted... But don't most of those small computers have firmwares that don't _use_ the GPT at all? Where does their boot process stop – before U-Boot, before Linux, within Linux?

Comment: Those small computers often have proprietary firmware, and the boot process sometimes stops in a device-dependent fashion (eg. NVIdia logo vs. black screen boot loop for older Jetson, short blinks of SD card activity lamp for Raspi, but also "sd-card icon" on newer Raspis etc.) . Or kernel panic by missing root paritiion on Raspi too. So the same cause has different symptopms, depending on the capabilities of the firmware to handle it, yes. But this is just from long-term experience, I will report back here what the next occasions show to me precisely.

Comment: The only thing surely in common is that the problem originates from cloning between different medias and rewriting sane GPT tables by gdisk fix the issues.

Comment: You'd need a more flexible and intelligent image/restore tool that adepts partition tables, the location of Secondary GPT and such. I think you know this so I am wondering what it actually is that you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this is to be expected:

[image]

The Secondary GPT is expected to be at a specific LBA address relative to the end of the drive or better said total or max LBAs. If you then change this (max LBA) due to different hardware, things will break unless you move for example the Secondary GPT to match requirements.

IOW if you'll be imaging/restoring such disk image files to different sized drives, you need a tool that takes matters like that into account.

And then you could still have a problem when restoring to a drive that is smaller unless you resize file systems (down-size).

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to adapt... I just wonder why vendor-shipped images do work if "just written" (eg. with dd) to a different-size disk. This is my experience with RaspberryPi, NVidia Jetson and Odroid devices. Just that I am not able myself to create those images...